# pretty print of boost::multi_array example fails

Tags: c++, boost, multidimensional-array

I have this smart and cool [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_array/example/print_array.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
#include "boost/array.hpp"
#include "boost/cstdlib.hpp"

template <typename Array>
void print(std::ostream& os, const Array& A)
{
  typename Array::const_iterator i;
  os << "[";
  for (i = A.begin(); i != A.end(); ++i) {
    print(os, *i);
    if (boost::next(i) != A.end())
      os << ',';
  }
  os << "]";
}
void print(std::ostream& os, const double& x)
{
  os << x;
}
int main()
{
  typedef   boost::multi_array<double, 2> array;
  double values[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    3, 4, 5 
  };
  const int values_size=6;
  array A(boost::extents[2][3]);
  A.assign(values,values+values_size);
  print(std::cout, A);
  return boost::exit_success;
}
```

But if I try to compile it: **g++ -I/usr/include/boost/ b.cpp** I get this error:

```
b.cpp: In function ‘void print(std::ostream&, const Array&) [with Array = double]’:
b.cpp:12:   instantiated from ‘void print(std::ostream&, const Array&) [with Array = boost::detail::multi_array::const_sub_array<double, 1u, const double*>]’
b.cpp:12:   instantiated from ‘void print(std::ostream&, const Array&) [with Array = main()::array]’
b.cpp:32:   instantiated from here
b.cpp:9: error: ‘double’ is not a class, struct, or union type
b.cpp:11: error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘A’, which is of non-class type ‘const double’
b.cpp:9: error: ‘double’ is not a class, struct, or union type
b.cpp:9: error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘A’, which is of non-class type ‘const double’
b.cpp:9: error: ‘double’ is not a class, struct, or union type
b.cpp:9: error: ‘double’ is not a class, struct, or union type
b.cpp:9: error: ‘double’ is not a class, struct, or union type
b.cpp:13: error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘A’, which is of non-class type ‘const double’
b.cpp:9: error: ‘double’ is not a class, struct, or union type

shell returned 1
```

What was wrong? It seems to not understand the difference between the first and the second **print** function. Maybe some compiler options I missed?

EDIT:
If i use template<> as Craig H answer i resolve the problem in a isolated example.cpp. But if i put the 2 functions in a separate .h file in my project, the error appears again!

Answer (score 1):

In this example you created a template function as your first print function then declare another function that implements a specific version of that template without template specializing.  I think if you change the following line

```
void print(std::ostream& os, const double& x)
```

to

```
template<> void print<double>(std::ostream& os, const double& x)
```

your problem should go away.

Comment: you're right! so, what is this? a bug in boost example? how to say that to boost guys?

Comment: I didn't see the link when you first posted this, but that does look like an error in the boost example.  Template specializing is the way of telling the compiler that the function is a specific version of the template function for a specific type.  If you are interested this site: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/ has a great description of templates and specialization.

Comment: thanks for the link! but i have another problem. if i include this 2 functions in .h in my applications i get this error: **multiple definition of `void print_multi_array<double>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, double const&)'**

Comment: also with static keyword doesn't compile.. : (